# How to group overlapping ranges of substrings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionary in the following format:

```
ldict = [
{'start_offset': 0, 'end_offset': 10, 'string_type': 'verb'},
{'start_offset': 5, 'end_offset': 15, 'string_type': 'noun'},
{'start_offset': 20, 'end_offset': 30, 'string_type': 'noun'},
{'start_offset': 42, 'end_offset': 51, 'string_type': 'adj'},
{'start_offset': 45, 'end_offset': 52, 'string_type': 'noun'}
]
```

The `start_offset` and `end_offset` indicate the start and end positions of a substring in a string.

My aim is to group together overlapping strings to form one row only.
The `start_offset` would be the lowest position and the `end_offset` would be the highest position.

Example of output:

```
ldict = [
{'start_offset': 0, 'end_offset': 15, 'string_type': ['verb', 'noun']},
{'start_offset': 20, 'end_offset': 30, 'string_type': ['noun']},
{'start_offset': 42, 'end_offset': 52, 'string_type': ['adj', 'noun']}
]
```

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
final = []
for row in ldict:
  i1 = pd.Interval(row['start_offset'], row['end_offset'])
  semi_fin_list = []
  for one_row in ldict:
     i2 = pd.Interval(one_row['start_offset'], one_row['end_offset'])
     if i1.overlaps(i2):
         semi_fin_list.append(once)
  final.append(semi_fin_list)
```

In the attempt above, I could get the overlaps for a row but was stuck on what I could do next to sort and combine the rows to keep distinct rows.

How could I achieve the same? My attempt has not reached the conclusion as I still get duplicates.

Comment: Iterate over list, compare offsets in dictionaries and group overlapping.

Comment: ...with algorithm. What did you try?

Comment: I am stuck. I did try a nested for loop where one row is compared with all others but I got duplicate rows with no idea how to sort them.

Comment: @nifeco, please add your code to question.

Comment: @martineau I am only asking for help, no need for you to be rude.  I didn't add my code because i feel like it is wrong and there may be a better way of doing it that I don't know.

Comment: Telling you how things work around here is not being rude. If you're stuck, you haven't done enough research.

Comment: @nifeco, it's not a freelance resource, if you want to get help, show what have you already done. It's quite simple task, nested loop is not required, just single `for` and condition.

Comment: @OlvinRoght it took time to write the attempted code as I am writing it on a remote desktop where I can't copy paste it.

Comment: @martineau it is an issue of logic in code that I cannot figure out as I am new to this field and decided to ask for ideas here. I know this is not a coding service. I am looking for a direction to solve this issue best from people around the world who have so much more experience than I do.

Comment: Fine, but this isn't the place for that. See [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Stackoverflow is to help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort based on `start_offset` before merging:

```
ldict = [
    {'start_offset': 0, 'end_offset': 10, 'string_type': 'verb'},
    {'start_offset': 5, 'end_offset': 15, 'string_type': 'noun'},
    {'start_offset': 20, 'end_offset': 30, 'string_type': 'noun'},
    {'start_offset': 42, 'end_offset': 51, 'string_type': 'adj'},
    {'start_offset': 45, 'end_offset': 52, 'string_type': 'noun'},
]
sorted_ldict = sorted(ldict, key=lambda d: d['start_offset'])
merged_ldict = [
    {
        'start_offset': sorted_ldict[0]['start_offset'],
        'end_offset': sorted_ldict[0]['end_offset'],
        'string_type': [sorted_ldict[0]['string_type']],
    }
]
for d in sorted_ldict[1:]:
    if d['start_offset'] > merged_ldict[-1]['end_offset']:
        merged_ldict.append(
            {
                'start_offset': d['start_offset'],
                'end_offset': d['end_offset'],
                'string_type': [d['string_type']],
            }
        )
    else:
        merged_ldict[-1]['end_offset'] = \
            max(merged_ldict[-1]['end_offset'], d['end_offset'])
        if d['string_type'] not in merged_ldict[-1]['string_type']:
            merged_ldict[-1]['string_type'].append(d['string_type'])
print(merged_ldict)
```

**Output:**

```
[
     {'start_offset': 0, 'end_offset': 15, 'string_type': ['verb', 'noun']}, 
     {'start_offset': 20, 'end_offset': 30, 'string_type': ['noun']}, 
     {'start_offset': 42, 'end_offset': 52, 'string_type': ['adj', 'noun']}
]
```

**Note:** *You could consider using something like a **[dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)** rather than a raw dictionary.*

Answer (score 1):

```py
ldict = [
    {'start_offset': 0, 'end_offset': 10, 'string_type': 'verb'},
    {'start_offset': 5, 'end_offset': 15, 'string_type': 'noun'},
    {'start_offset': 20, 'end_offset': 30, 'string_type': 'noun'},
    {'start_offset': 42, 'end_offset': 51, 'string_type': 'adj'},
    {'start_offset': 45, 'end_offset': 52, 'string_type': 'noun'}
]

string_type = []
new_ldict = []
i = 0
while i < len(ldict):
    start_offset = ldict[i]['start_offset']
    end_offset = ldict[i]['end_offset']
    string_type = [ldict[i]['string_type']]
    while i + 1 < len(ldict) and ldict[i + 1]['start_offset'] <= end_offset:
        end_offset = ldict[i + 1]['end_offset']
        string_type.append(ldict[i + 1]['string_type'])
        i += 1

    new_ldict.append({'stat_offset': start_offset, 'end_offset': end_offset, 'string_type': string_type})
    i += 1
print(new_ldict)
```

Output:

```
[{'stat_offset': 0, 'end_offset': 15, 'string_type': ['verb', 'noun']}, {'stat_offset': 20, 'end_offset': 30, 'string_type': ['noun']}, {'stat_offset': 42, 'end_offset': 52, 'string_type': ['adj', 'noun']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to iterate over `ldict` and compare `'end_offset'` of previous item to `start_offset` of current. Assuming your `ldict` is sorted by `'start_offset'` you can use next code:

```py
res = []
for d in ldict:
    if not res or d['start_offset'] > last['end_offset']:
        last = {**d, 'string_type': [d['string_type']]}
        res.append(last)
    else:
        last['end_offset'] = d['end_offset']
        last['string_type'].append(d['string_type'])
```

If your `ldict` is not sorted, you should sort it before:

```py
from operator import itemgetter

...

ldict = sorted(ldict, key=itemgetter('start_offset'))
```

Output:

```
[
    {'start_offset': 0, 'end_offset': 15, 'string_type': ['verb', 'noun']},
    {'start_offset': 20, 'end_offset': 30, 'string_type': ['noun']},
    {'start_offset': 42, 'end_offset': 52, 'string_type': ['adj', 'noun']}
]
```